# Change scrim color of BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

How do you change the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` scrim color - the dim overlay color?

You can do this for `DrawerLayout` via `drawerLayout.setScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.dimOverlay))`

[image]

Comment: That's actually the dimming inherent to `Dialog`s. I don't think there's really any easy way to change that color. However, `BottomSheetDialog` covers the whole screen, so you should be able to just set its background to whatever color you like; e.g., in your `BottomSheetDialogFragment` subclass, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vItTnGv89Dqnz9EueBIp0s4Jpyd2ctpN/view?usp=drivesdk. I can't really test that right now. The `dimAmount` setting is somewhat optional, as the default dim should just act as an alpha multiplier, I think. You can play around with it.

Comment: Well, there is a difference, you can see the custom background drawable slide up as it appears, whereas the default background fades in instead.

Comment: The dimAmount also isn't behaving as expected, even 0.0001f is quite opaque

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense, about the slide-in. For a bottom sheet, it'd be natural to have the default animation slide up from the bottom. I'll see what we can do about that, when I get a chance later. Hopefully it's not too ugly if we change that to a fade-in. I'm not sure exactly what you mean about the dim, but you can just turn that off completely – e.g., `dimAmount = 0f`, alternatively `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND)` – and control it all with the background color and alpha. I just mentioned that as an FYI, really. Easier without it anyway, probably.

Comment: Thanks that worked! To clarify my earlier statement, `dimAmount = 0.1f` doesn't set the alpha of the background color to 10% as you'd expect. Yes 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque, but some really small number is not really transparent it's still quite opaque, so it's impossible to obtain 10% opacity for example. Seems it's a weighted scaled amount.

Comment: Not relevant to this question but interesting: using the same color for the scrim color on DrawerLayout results in different colored outcome, seems that has an additional dark overlay (that doesn't apply to the action bar )

Answer (score 4):

You can change background of `Window` and set you want transparent color.

```
@Override
public @NotNull Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorPrimaryTransparent);
    return dialog;
}
```