# Modal bottom sheet - No dimming (scrim) of content underneath (Material Components Library)

Tags: android, material-components-android, bottom-sheet, android-modalbottomsheetlayout

Following the basic description on how to use the modal bottom sheet in the Android Material Components Library, there is no dimming of the content underneath the bottom sheet, even though the image in [BottomSheet.md](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheet.md) clearly shows dimming. This document also describes the dimming as a scrim, but there is no attribute exposed to set the scrim. I created a barebones app using the provided code in that doc, but there is no dimming.

**Expected behavior:** There should be dimming, or the ability to set the scrim of the content underneath the bottom sheet.

**Source code:**

```
class ModalBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.modal_bottom_sheet_content, container, false)

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "ModalBottomSheet"
    }
}

 val modalBottomSheet = ModalBottomSheet()
 modalBottomSheet.show(supportFragmentManager, ModalBottomSheet.TAG)
```

**Minimal sample app repro:** See code snippet.

[image]

**Android API version:** 33

**Material Library version:** 1.9.0

**Device:** Pixel 6 emulator

Comment: It seems a bug on API 33 only. I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65830721) that solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah it seems like an emulator bug

Comment: Hope this will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77610325/16411959